# CCK text field does not appear in views fields nor filters

Tags: 6, entities, views

I have a CCK text field in my TOC. However, it is not displayed for selection under the views fields nor the views filters.

I tried clearing cache and refreshing the module list with no luck.

Any hint of what could be happening?

Comment: Have you checked permissions?

Comment: Other fields in the same TOC are visible. I have installed no field access permissions module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had in Views -> Tools the option "Disable views data caching" unchecked. Fixed now, thanks for your help!